# Plotting a scatterplot/bubbleChart along with Columnrange graph in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have requirement to achieve using highcharts. below is the chart that I have to plot.
[image: column range graph]

I was able to plot the horizontal bar using columnrange chart type in highchart used tickposition array to get the flags,
but the bubbles, I am not able figure out how to do it. Every bubble has a tooltip as well.
Below is the jsfiddle to create the columnrange chart seen below.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hkr30270/29/)`

```
function _getDiamondGraphLabel(head, body, lvl, positionLeft, primeColor) {
                    var positionedTopClass = '',
                        headFormatted = '',
                        bodyFormatted = '',
                        positionedLeftClass = '';

                    if (lvl) {
                        positionedTopClass = 'diamond-graph-label-lvl-' + lvl;
                    }

                    if (positionLeft) {
                        positionedLeftClass = 'diamond-graph-label-left';
                    }

                    headFormatted = '<div class="diamond-graph-head-label">' + head + '</div>';
                    bodyFormatted = '<div class="diamond-graph-body-label"><b>' + body + '</b></div>';

                    var retVal = '<div ' + (primeColor ? 'style="border-color: ' + primeColor + '; border-width: 3px"' : '') + ' class="diamond-graph-label ' +
                        positionedTopClass + ' ' + positionedLeftClass + '""><div class="diamond-graph-label-content" ' +
                        (primeColor ? 'style="background-color: ' + primeColor + ' ; color: white"' : '') + '>' + headFormatted + bodyFormatted + '</div></div>';

                    return retVal;
                }

var min = 49560,
    per10 = 49560,
  per25 = 63560,
  per75 = 102537,
  per90 = 119537,
  median = 83362,
  average = 89142,
  max = 119537,
  counter = 0;
var tickerPositions = [min, per10, per25, per75, per90, median, average, max];
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'columnrange',
                        inverted: true,
                        plotBackgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
                        height: 25,
                        plotHeight: 60,
                        width: $('#container')[0].clientWidth,
                        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        tickLength: 0,
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        tickPositions: tickerPositions,
                        labels: {
                            useHTML: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                // There is a bug in Highcharts that formatter is calling twice. (reset if the value is higher than tickers length)
                                if (counter >= tickerPositions.length) {
                                    counter = 0;
                                }

                                counter++;

                                switch (counter) {
                                    case 2:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('10th', this.value, 0, false, '#000');

                                    case 3:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('25th', this.value, 1, false, '#000');

                                    case 4:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('75th', this.value, 1, true, '#000');

                                    case 5:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('90th', this.value, 0, true, '#000');

                                    case 6:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel("Median", this.value, 2, average < median, "#000");

                                    case 7:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel("Average", this.value, 2, average > median, '#000');

                                    default:
                                        return '<div></div>';
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        columnrange: {
                            grouping: false,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            pointPadding: 0,
                            groupPadding: 0
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'MinTo10th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: min,
                            high: per10
                        }],
                        color: '#ebebeb'
                    }, {
                        name: '10thTo25th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per10,
                            high: per25
                        }],
                        color: '#bbbbbb'
                    }, {
                        name: '25thTo75th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per25,
                            high: per75
                        }],
                        color: '#6a6a6a'
                    }, {
                        name: '75thTo90th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per75,
                            high: per90
                        }],
                        color: '#bbbbbb'
                    }, {
                        name: '90thToMax',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per90,
                            high: max
                        }],
                        color: '#ebebeb'
                    }, {
                        name: 'median',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: median,
                            high: median + 1
                        }],
                        color: '#1a8099'

                    }, {
                        name: 'average',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: average,
                            high: average + 1
                        }],
                        color: '#006699'
                    }]
                });
```

`

Help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: When you say "I am not able figure out how to do it", can you be more specific? What aspect of plotting the bubbles are you having trouble with? You're going to have to do some calculations based on 1) the scale of your axes, and 2) the size you want the bubbles to be in order to figure out what `x` and `y` values to use to place them. It will be much easier to help if you provide an example with the bubbles plotted in some to start with though, rather than just the bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `xrange` type instead of columnrange+inverted. Then use simply `scatter` type to render bubbles/markers. If you can use Highstock, then flags can be achieved as `flag` type series. Unfortunately, you need to calculate all marker positions. Note: you can define your own shape for flags.

Alternative solution is to use [`Renderer`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer) and manually render all markers.

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3L3ofh0a/18/

Snippet:

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    min: -5,
    max: 5
  },
  xAxis: {
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    min: 45000,
    max: 150000
  },
  series: [{
    data: [{
        x: 50000,   
        x2: 60000,
        y: 1,
        color: '#ebebeb'
      },
      {
        x: 60000,
        x2: 90000,
        y: 1,
        color: '#bbbbbb'
      },
      {
        x: 90000,
        x2: 100000,
        y: 1,
        color: '#6a6a6a'
      },
      {
        x: 100000,
        x2: 102000,
        y: 1,
        color: '#bbbbbb'
      },
      {
        x: 102000,
        x2: 120000,
        y: 1,
        color: '#ebebeb'
      }
    ],
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    type: 'xrange',
    id: 'top'
    // the event marker flags
  }, {
    data: [{
        x: 60000,
        x2: 70000,
        y: -1,
        color: '#ebebeb'
      },
      {
        x: 70000,
        x2: 95000,
        y: -1,
        color: '#bbbbbb'
      },
      {
        x: 95000,
        x2: 98000,
        y: -1,
        color: '#6a6a6a'
      },
      {
        x: 98000,
        x2: 102000,
        y: -1,
        color: '#bbbbbb'
      },
      {
        x: 102000,
        x2: 105000,
        y: -1,
        color: '#ebebeb'
      }
    ],
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    type: 'xrange',
    id: 'bottom'
    // the event marker flags
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    data: [{
      x: 50000,
      y: 1,
      title: '10th<br>50000',
      text: '10th<br>50000'
    }, {
      x: 120000,
      title: '90th<br>120000',
      y: 1,
      text: '90th<br>120000'
    }],
    y: -55
  }, {
    type: 'flags',
    data: [{
      x: 60000,
      y: 1,
      title: '25th<br>60000',
      text: '25th<br>60000'
    }, {
      x: 102000,
      title: '75th<br>102000',
      y: 1,
      text: '75th<br>102000'
    }],
    y: -95
  }, {
    type: 'scatter',
    data: [
      [61000, -2],
      [63500, -2],
      [66000, -2],
      [66000, -2.4],
    ]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

We are not using Highstocks in our app so, I can't use flag series.
I tried plotting two different graphs, and that worked.(One is columnrange, other one is scatterplot). But the only concern is to align the tick positions of the both graphs so the scaling of the graphs match. 
[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkr30270/236/) is the link to it.

```
    Highcharts.SVGRenderer.prototype.symbols.sai = function (x, y, w, h) {
    return ['M', x, y + h / 2, 'L', x + w, y + h / 2, 'M', x + w / 2, y, 'L', x + w / 2, y + h, 'z'];
};

function _getDiamondGraphLabel(head, body, lvl, positionLeft, primeColor) {
                    var positionedTopClass = '',
                        headFormatted = '',
                        bodyFormatted = '',
                        positionedLeftClass = '';

                    if (lvl) {
                        positionedTopClass = 'diamond-graph-label-lvl-' + lvl;
                    }

                    if (positionLeft) {
                        positionedLeftClass = 'diamond-graph-label-left';
                    }

                    headFormatted = '<div class="diamond-graph-head-label">' + head + '</div>';
                    bodyFormatted = '<div class="diamond-graph-body-label"><b>' + body + '</b></div>';

                    var retVal = '<div ' + (primeColor ? 'style="border-color: ' + primeColor + '; border-width: 3px"' : '') + ' class="diamond-graph-label ' +
                        positionedTopClass + ' ' + positionedLeftClass + '""><div class="diamond-graph-label-content" ' +
                        (primeColor ? 'style="background-color: ' + primeColor + ' ; color: white"' : '') + '>' + headFormatted + bodyFormatted + '</div></div>';

                    return retVal;
                }

var min = 49560,
    per10 = 49560,
  per25 = 63560,
  per75 = 102537,
  per90 = 119537,
  median = 83362,
  average = 89142,
  max = 119537,
  counter = 0;
var tickerPositions = [min, per10, per25, per75, per90, median, average, max];
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'columnrange',
                        inverted: true,
                        plotBackgroundColor: '#e9e9e9',
                        height: 25,
                        plotHeight: 60,
                        width: $('#container')[0].clientWidth,
                        spacing: [0, 0, 0, 0]
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        tickLength: 0,
                        labels: {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        tickPositions: tickerPositions,
                        labels: {
                            useHTML: true,
                            formatter: function () {
                                // There is a bug in Highcharts that formatter is calling twice. (reset if the value is higher than tickers length)
                                if (counter >= tickerPositions.length) {
                                    counter = 0;
                                }

                                counter++;

                                switch (counter) {
                                    case 2:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('10th', this.value, 0, false, '#000');

                                    case 3:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('25th', this.value, 1, false, '#000');

                                    case 4:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('75th', this.value, 1, true, '#000');

                                    case 5:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel('90th', this.value, 0, true, '#000');

                                    case 6:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel("Median", this.value, 2, average < median, "#000");

                                    case 7:
                                        return _getDiamondGraphLabel("Average", this.value, 2, average > median, '#000');

                                    default:
                                        return '<div></div>';
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    exporting: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        columnrange: {
                            grouping: false,
                            borderWidth: 0,
                            pointPadding: 0,
                            groupPadding: 0
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'MinTo10th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: min,
                            high: per10
                        }],
                        color: '#ebebeb'
                    }, {
                        name: '10thTo25th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per10,
                            high: per25
                        }],
                        color: '#bbbbbb'
                    }, {
                        name: '25thTo75th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per25,
                            high: per75
                        }],
                        color: '#6a6a6a'
                    }, {
                        name: '75thTo90th',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per75,
                            high: per90
                        }],
                        color: '#bbbbbb'
                    }, {
                        name: '90thToMax',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: per90,
                            high: max
                        }],
                        color: '#ebebeb'
                    }, {
                        name: 'median',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: median,
                            high: median + 1
                        }],
                        color: '#1a8099'

                    }, {
                        name: 'average',
                        stack: 'DIAMOND_STACK',
                        data: [{
                            x: 0,
                            low: average,
                            high: average + 1
                        }],
                        color: '#006699'
                    }]
                });


Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'scatter',

        plotBackgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },


    xAxis: {
            min:min,
        max: per90,
        lineWidth:0,
        labels: {
        enabled: false,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        tickLength: 0
        }
    },
    title:{
    text: ''
    },
    yAxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
        enabled: false
        },
       min:0,
       max:10,
       title:{
       text:''
       }
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                    symbol:'circle',
                radius: 5,
                lineColor: '#2c8dab',
                lineWidth: 4,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false,
                        lineColor: '#2c8dab'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Employee',
        color: '#2c8dab',
        data:[[min, 10], [63650, 10], [min, 9.1], [63650, 9.1]]
    },
    {
        name: 'Employee',
        color: '#2c8dab',
        marker: {
            radius:5,
          symbol: 'sai',
          lineWidth: 1.5,
          lineColor: '#fff'
        },
        data:[[min, 9.1]]
    }]
});
```